# Changing ownership of home folders

Tags: command-line, filesystem, permissions

Okay, so I have a bit of a self-created problem.  We were running out of space for SVN, so I moved our home folders to a new (much bigger) partition.  This seemed to work fine at first, and SVN itself seems to be working no problem, as do file shares and so on... except I can no longer log in to Gnome.

When I log in, I get a message telling me .dmrc can't be locked, and that the home folder must be owned by the user with 644 permissions.  That sounds straightforward enough, so I log into an the fail-safe terminal to fix it.

Logging in, I can see that the home folders are owned by root now (I assume this was a by-product of when I copied them).  For some reason though, changing the owner with chown always tells me it's an invalid operation.  Even if I use sudo I get that message.

I've tried changing both ownership and permission on these folders and neither is working for me.  Help?

I'm trying this:

```
sudo chown -R username /home/username
```

Comment: You should probably remount the partition in read-write mode.

Comment: Can you confirm the exact error message is "invalid operation" and not something similar like "operation not permitted"? It makes a big difference. I've never seen chown give "invalid operation" before myself. What filesystem is the new bigger partition? Are you sure it's a filesystem which supports chown?

Answer (score 11):

To flesh out the answer a bit, you may want to look at chown's man file before you do anything, but to change the owner of all files in /home/user, you'd do:

```
chown -hvR user /home/user
```

where "user" is the name of the owner you want to change it to.

Comment: the -v option can get quite excessive and make the task take *felt* longer.

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
sudo su -

chown -R username:username /home/username/
```

Comment: I'm not sure how this differs substantially (apart from setting the group, which you didn't explain) from what the OP has already tried in his Question?

Comment: as root, instead of sudo.  include group (as you noted).

Comment: Running as root instead of sudo is irrelevant.